# How can I link a WebDAV URL within windows explorer (w7) to a regular folder instead of using a network link (standard)?

Tags: webdav

Normally a WebDAV URL shows up as a network link within the table of root directory trees (c:/; d:/). I would like the WebDAV URL to be accessed from a regular folder e.g. c:/user/download.

How do I link the URL manually and/ or using the msdn WebDAV API for script configuration?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any windows clients that can mount a drive into a local file system. A couple of options

- Mount a drive like normal and then use a linked folder (ok, not a great option)
- Use a file sync client to sync a local folder to the webdav server

There are a handful of sync clients around. Here's a new one that looks nice, although i havent used it - https://www.syncany.org/

Comment: I need the feature for a product. a third party service is not an option. does someone know if the msdn library/ API could work?

Comment: I know MS Office has built-in sync features which could *in theory* be used. However, I dont know if those features are publicly exposes, and even if they are i would be very surprised if the API was stable enough to build on.
You might be able to embed a sync library in your product, eg:
https://dragotin.wordpress.com/tag/mirall/